# append new node in XML in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Hello Friends i am working on classic ASP project and i am using an XML file to do CRUD Operation. When file does not exist it is working fine to save data in it but file already exist how to append new record data in it ? my code :

```
If Not objFSO.FileExists( xmlFile ) Then 

                objFSO.CreateTextFile( xmlFile )
                set objWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile( xmlFile, 2 )
                objWrite.WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>")
                objWrite.WriteLine(tb & "<Slider>")
                objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<Header>" & Uploader.Form("headerText") & "</Header>")
                objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<Image>" & File.FileName & "</Image>")
                objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<Link>" & Uploader.Form("linkcontentText") & "</Link>")
                objWrite.WriteLine(tb & tb & "<Description>" & Uploader.Form("SliderText") & "</Description>")
                objWrite.WriteLine(tb & "</Slider>")

            End IF
            If objFSO.FileExists( xmlFile ) Then
            'append code , i have tried this but not working
            Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
              xmlDoc.async = False
              xmlDoc.load(Server.MapPath(xmlFile)
              Set fieldName = xmlDoc.createElement("Slider")
              Set attID = xmlDoc.createAttribute("Header")
              Set attID1 = xmlDoc.createAttribute("Image")
              Set attID2 = xmlDoc.createAttribute("Link")
              Set attID3 = xmlDoc.createAttribute("Description")
              attID.Text =  Uploader.Form("headerText")
              attID1.Text = File.FileName
              attID2.Text = Uploader.Form("linkcontentText")
              attID3.Text = Uploader.Form("SliderText")
              fieldName.setAttributeNode attID 
              fieldName.setAttributeNode attID1
              fieldName.setAttributeNode attID2
              fieldName.setAttributeNode attID3
              'xmlDoc.a
              'xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("menu1.xml"))

            End If
```

please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: Generally, don't use `ISO-8859-1` in new projects. Use `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 4):

Obvious error:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

should be:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
```

Whether this solves **all** of your problems, remains to be seen.